# How to get Sum with group by in Django query

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get Sum of my quantity with the group by product_id but it returns multiple records.

I am working on Django and trying to get sum with group by so. I try with annotate and values.

```
productinventory_ds = (
                ProductInventory.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
                .values("product_id")
                .annotate(
                    instock_quantity_s=Sum("instock_quantity"),
                    delivered_quantity_s=Sum("delivered_quantity"),
                )
            )
```

But instead of giving one product id and sum of all the quantity. this query returns multiple results with the same product id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `.order_by(..)` to force grouping, like:

```
productinventory_ds = ProductInventory.objects.filter(
    product_id=product_id
).values('product_id').annotate(
    instock_quantity_s=Sum('instock_quantity'),
    delivered_quantity_s=Sum('delivered_quantity')
).order_by('product_id')
```

Here however it looks like you want to extract the columns for a *single* `product_id`. In that case, `.aggregate(..)` makes more sense:

```
productinventory_ds = ProductInventory.objects.filter(
    product_id=product_id
).aggregate(
    instock_quantity_s=Sum('instock_quantity'),
    delivered_quantity_s=Sum('delivered_quantity')
)
```

This will return a dictionary that contains two items with as keys `'instock_quantity_s'` and `'delivered_quantity_s'`.